# Change font of div css

Tags: html, css

I am having a hard time understanding how to change the font of a div line under an h2 header.  I have tried to find information about this online but only inline or if the header is already classified as a class.  I cannot edit the html code, I can only modify the css file.  I have also tried defining the the header and then the div element by writing Class examples.Example 1 Class CSS and then writing the code.  Is it an issue because you cannot have spaces within the div class?

```css
*
{
 background-color: #ffcc66;
 color: #003399;
 font-family: Comic Sans MS;
 font-size: 14px;
}
a
{
 color: #CC0000;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited
{
 color: #CC0000;
}
a:hover
{
 color: #006600;
}
a:active
{
 color: #CC0000;
}

h1
{
 background-color: #3399FF;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 35px;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-bottom-width: thin;
 border-bottom-color: #000033;
}

h2
{
 color: #333333;
 font-weight: bold;
}

p
{
 font-family: Georgia;
 color: #003300;
 padding: 15px;
}

li
{
 font-family: Arial;
 background-color: #808080;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Formatting with CSS</h1>

<p>This is a basic web page to be used as a test for applying  CSS formatting rules.</p>

<h2>Hyperlinks</h2>
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Link to the Google website</a>
<br/>
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Link to the google page on CSS</a>

<h2>List Items</h2>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>

<h2>Class examples</h2>
<div>Example 1 Class CSS</div>
<div>Example 2 Class CSS</div>
<div>Example 3 Class CSS</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to target the `<div>`s under 'Class Examples'?

Comment: Yes, I was each div to have a specific font different from one another.

Comment: Can you edit the HTML at all? If not, you can use `nth-of-type` selector. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to change each div font by without modifying the html. The idea is to target each give using adjacent sibling eg `h2 + div` , `h2 + div + div`, `h2 + div + div + div` etc. like so

```css
    
    *
    {
     background-color: #ffcc66;
     color: #003399;
     font-family: Comic Sans MS;
     font-size: 14px;
    }
    a
    {
     color: #CC0000;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:visited
    {
     color: #CC0000;
    }
    a:hover
    {
     color: #006600;
    }
    a:active
    {
     color: #CC0000;
    }
    
    h1
    {
     background-color: #3399FF;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 35px;
     border-bottom-style: solid;
     border-bottom-width: thin;
     border-bottom-color: #000033;
    }
    
    h2
    {
     color: red;
     font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    p
    {
     font-family: Georgia;
     color: #003300;
     padding: 15px;
    }
    
    li
    {
     font-family: Arial;
     background-color: #808080;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    *
{
 background-color: #ffcc66;
 color: #003399;
 font-family: Comic Sans MS;
 font-size: 14px;
}
a
{
 color: #CC0000;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited
{
 color: #CC0000;
}
a:hover
{
 color: #006600;
}
a:active
{
 color: #CC0000;
}

h1
{
 background-color: #3399FF;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 35px;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-bottom-width: thin;
 border-bottom-color: #000033;
}

h2
{
 color: red;
 font-weight: bold;
}

p
{
 font-family: Georgia;
 color: #003300;
 padding: 15px;
}

li
{
 font-family: Arial;
 background-color: #808080;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
}

h2 + div{
  font-family: Arial;
}

h2 + div + div{
  font-family:  Sakkal Majalla;
}

h2 + div + div + div{
  font-family: Batang;
}
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    <h1>Formatting with CSS</h1>
    
    <p>This is a basic web page to be used as a test for applying  CSS formatting rules.</p>
    
    <h2>Hyperlinks</h2>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">Link to the Google website</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">Link to the google page on CSS</a>
    
    <h2>List Items</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
    
    <h2>Class examples</h2>
    <div>Example 1 Class CSS</div>
    <div>Example 2 Class CSS</div>
    <div>Example 3 Class CSS</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Welcome. kindly mark it. so others can know it is helpful.@FUSIONCHA0S

Answer (score 1):

You can use nth-of-type since you only have individual divs [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efustLjk/)

```css
*
{
 background-color: #ffcc66;
 color: #003399;
 font-family: Comic Sans MS;
 font-size: 14px;
}
a
{
 color: #CC0000;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited
{
 color: #CC0000;
}
a:hover
{
 color: #006600;
}
a:active
{
 color: #CC0000;
}

h1
{
 background-color: #3399FF;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 35px;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-bottom-width: thin;
 border-bottom-color: #000033;
}

h2
{
 color: #333333;
 font-weight: bold;
}

p
{
 font-family: Georgia;
 color: #003300;
 padding: 15px;
}

li
{
 font-family: Arial;
 background-color: #808080;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
}

div:nth-of-type(1){
  font-family: Arial;
}
div:nth-of-type(2){
  font-family: fantasy;
}
div:nth-of-type(3){
  font-family: Trebuchet;
}
```

```html
<h1>Formatting with CSS</h1>

<p>This is a basic web page to be used as a test for applying  CSS formatting rules.</p>

<h2>Hyperlinks</h2>
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Link to the Google website</a>
<br/>
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Link to the google page on CSS</a>

<h2>List Items</h2>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>

<h2>Class examples</h2>
<div>Example 1 Class CSS</div>
<div>Example 2 Class CSS</div>
<div>Example 3 Class CSS</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Adjacent sibling combinator

```
h2 + div {
  background-color: #808080;
}
```

this will only affect the immediate sibling of (the next element after) the h2 element

more about css combinators [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This will work in your code.

```
div:first-of-type {
    /*Your Styles Here*/
}
```

Regards,